# Make an SKSpriteNode transparent

Tags: swift, skspritenode, invisible

Is it possible to make an SKSpriteNode totally transparent, while keeping its dimensions? If so, how? I want the object to still have a physicsBody and still be a child of gameScene, however I don't want it to be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SKSpriteNode`'s superclass `SKNode` has a member called `alpha` which let you set the opacity of the node I think it might not affect your sprite Physics.

```
let spriteNode = SKSpriteNode() // You should already have it
spriteNode.alpha = 0.0          // This should make your node transparent without affecting its physics interactions
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just **hide** your **node** with this simple line.

```
yourNode.hidden = true
```

Comment: Would that still allow me to see the node?

Comment: In my game it just worked totally fine. You are not able to see the node but the physicsBody worked for me.

Comment: Well if I can't see the node and it doesn't interact with anything then for all intents and purposes I could just remove the node all together